# Why is the console throwing the error "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)"?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
input_queue = queue.Queue()
payStubs_queue = queue.Queue()


'''Writing to CSV file'''
fields = ['ID', 'Name', 'Title', 'Hours Worked', 'Hourly Wage', 'Federal Tax Rate'] 
    
rows = [ ['1234', 'Nikhil', 'COE', '2', '9.0', '.20'], 
         ['1234', 'Sanchit', 'COE', '2', '9.1''.20'], 
         ['1234', 'Aditya', 'IT', '2', '9.3''.20'], 
         ['1234', 'Sagar', 'SE', '1', '9.5''.20'], 
         ['1234', 'Prateek', 'MCE', '3', '7.8''.20'], 
         ['1234', 'Sahil', 'EP', '2', '9.1''.20']] 
    
filename = "university_records.csv"   

with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
    csvwriter.writerow(fields) 
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)

'''Reading File'''
with open('university_records.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_file:
        #try:
            emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = line.strip().split(", ")
            employee = Employee(emp_id, first_name, job_title, float(hours_worked), float(hourly_wage), float(federal_tax_rate))
            input_queue.put(employee)
        #except ValueError:
            #continue
```

Full Traceback Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\fskid\OneDrive\Documents\Data Structures Fall 2023\Homework_Three_Python\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = line.strip().split(", ")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)
PS C:\Users\fskid\OneDrive\Documents\Data Structures Fall 2023\Homework_Three_Python>
```

I am new to Python so this may be an easy fix but no matter what I do I cant get this to work.I am trying to read a bunch of employee information into a queue from a csv but it keeps throwing that error.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and post full traceback of the error message?

Comment: I don't know because you didn't give us the full error message that tells us the line number.

Comment: Don't put the data relevant to the question in the title, and like Andrej say, always include the full traceback for questions. In this case it seems pretty obvious what the problem is (and the traceback will have told you half of it) - the line `emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = line.strip().split(", ")` splits a string into 6 values and assigns them. But what if the string has fewer than 5 `", "`? (please also add some example data, and perhaps print what is being processed and share the last few lines of that)

Comment: I found the error, you're stripping on , but dont have commas anywhere

Comment: I think you should be iterating over the csv reader shouldn't you?  it also looks as though you're missing some commas in your `rows` definition.  `'9.1''.20'` is just `'9.1.20'`, but you likely want `'9.1', '.20'`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Just did sorry about that.

Comment: actually csv writer apparently has a default of separating fields by comma. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter

Comment: You created a reader, why not `for row in csv_reader:` and then `emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = row`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the obvious errors and typos in your code, we end up with:

```
import queue
import csv

input_queue = queue.Queue()

# Writing to CSV file
fields = ['ID', 'Name', 'Title', 'Hours Worked', 'Hourly Wage', 'Federal Tax Rate']

rows = [['1234', 'Nikhil', 'COE', '2', '9.0', '.20'],
        ['1234', 'Sanchit', 'COE', '2', '9.1', '.20'],
        ['1234', 'Aditya', 'IT', '2', '9.3', '.20'],
        ['1234', 'Sagar', 'SE', '1', '9.5', '.20'],
        ['1234', 'Prateek', 'MCE', '3', '7.8', '.20'],
        ['1234', 'Sahil', 'EP', '2', '9.1', '.20']]

filename = "university_records.csv"

with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)

# Reading File
with open('university_records.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_file:
        employee = emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = line.strip().split(", ")
        input_queue.put(employee)
```

This still has the problem that we can't know what `Employee` is. However, that's probably not needed for an answer.

Running your code, causes the error on this line:

```
emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = line.strip().split(", ")
```

That suggests there's a line in your csv that has fewer than 5 commas (which would cause it to get split in fewer than 6 parts).

If you look a the .csv generated, it's obvious:

```
ID,Name,Title,Hours Worked,Hourly Wage,Federal Tax Rate

1234,Nikhil,COE,2,9.0,.20

1234,Sanchit,COE,2,9.1,.20

1234,Aditya,IT,2,9.3,.20

1234,Sagar,SE,1,9.5,.20

1234,Prateek,MCE,3,7.8,.20

1234,Sahil,EP,2,9.1,.20
```

There's line endings there, resulting in empty lines with no commas. And your faulty data made it even worse:

```
ID,Name,Title,Hours Worked,Hourly Wage,Federal Tax Rate

1234,Nikhil,COE,2,9.0,.20

1234,Sanchit,COE,2,9.1.20

1234,Aditya,IT,2,9.3.20

1234,Sagar,SE,1,9.5.20

1234,Prateek,MCE,3,7.8.20

1234,Sahil,EP,2,9.1.20
```

Also note that there's no spaces after the commas.

Get rid of the empty lines, and deal with the commas:

```
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
   ...
```

And:

```
emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = (field.strip() for field in line.split(","))
```

This works just fine:

```
import csv

# Writing to CSV file
fields = ['ID', 'Name', 'Title', 'Hours Worked', 'Hourly Wage', 'Federal Tax Rate']

rows = [['1234', 'Nikhil', 'COE', '2', '9.0', '.20'],
        ['1234', 'Sanchit', 'COE', '2', '9.1', '.20'],
        ['1234', 'Aditya', 'IT', '2', '9.3', '.20'],
        ['1234', 'Sagar', 'SE', '1', '9.5', '.20'],
        ['1234', 'Prateek', 'MCE', '3', '7.8', '.20'],
        ['1234', 'Sahil', 'EP', '2', '9.1', '.20']]

filename = "university_records.csv"

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)

# Reading File
with open('university_records.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_file:
        emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = (field.strip() for field in line.split(","))
```

Comment: I got it fixed thanks to you guys great help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the usage of `split(", ")`.

This splits on the EXACT sequence comma-space.  But the actual csv file only has commas, not comma-space, between the fields.  So `split()` does not find anything to split.

Also, as @Grismar pointed out, your sample data is missing a comma between the final two fields for all the rows except the first.

Python interprets `'9.1''.20'` as the single string `'9.1.20'`.

You're missing a comma `'9.1', '.20'`.

Comment: @Grismar I stand by my answer.  The generated csv file clearly has only commas, not comma-space, between the fields.  `split(", ")` obviously cannot work in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSV file, so use the `csv_reader` you've already created. This will handle the comma separator, but will also add any needed escapes in your data.

```
with open('university_records.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        #try:
            emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = row
            employee = Employee(emp_id, first_name, job_title, float(hours_worked), float(hourly_wage), float(federal_tax_rate))
            input_queue.put(employee)
        #except ValueError:
            #continue
```